# Trying to sync google sheets to google calendar using apptscript, but getting error

Tags: google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I am getting an error when adding this code into the appscript.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'createEvent' of null
scheduleShifts  @ Code.gs:12

I am just copying and pasting the code from an online resource.

Can someone please help me figure out how to sync google sheet to google calendar,

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide your script as a text data instead of the image data? And, are there 2 questions in your question? Q1: You want to remove the error of `TypeError: Cannot read property 'createEvent' of null scheduleShifts @ Code.gs:12`. Q2: `Can someone please help me figure out how to sync google sheet to google calendar,`.

Comment: I just copied/pasted it from this website

https://medium.com/@dontmesswithjo/coding-basics-for-loops-90dca2873c70

function scheduleShifts() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var calendarID = spreadsheet.getRange("C4").getValue();
    var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("calendarId");
var signups = spreadsheet.getRange("A5:C7").getValues();
for (x=0; x<signups.length;x++)
{
    var shift = signups[x];
    var startTime = shift[0];
    var endTime = shift[1];
    var volunteer= shift[2];
    eventCal.createEvent(volunteer, startTime, endTime);
}
}

Comment: Thank you for replying. When you add your script as a text, can you add it to your question? Because when the script is put to the comment, the readability becomes low. When you add it to your question, please click the edit button of your question.

Comment: please edit your question and include code and not images of code.

Answer (score 1):

#### It looks like the error may here, on line 4

```
var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("calendarId")
```

This code is saying that the calendar ID is literally `calendarId`.

This is why the error says

> Cannot read property 'createEvent' of null

Because when you executed the above code, it could not find the calendar ID, so `eventCal` became `null`.

Since `null` is just "nothing" it doesn't have the method `createEvent`.

#### Solution

Change the code to:

```
var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarID)
```

**(Wihtout the `"`)**

Comment: When I saw the OP's script, it seems that `var calendarID = spreadsheet.getRange("C4").getValue();`. So in your answer, how about modifying to `var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarID)`?

Comment: Hello all, yes I found another code online where it did not have the " ". So I removed it. It now works.  Thank you all for helping!